# Does including the same figure placement specifier multiple times increase its weighting?

Tags: floats, positioning

I keep seeing `\begin{figure}[hhhhtbp]` in a report I'm coauthoring. I asked the other author about it, and he said that he was told that including the 'h' multiple times increased the weighting of that placement specifier.  However, my instincts tell me that the extra 'h's are redundant and that `\begin{figure}[hhhhtbp]` is exactly the same as `\begin{figure}[htbp]`, especially since an exclamation point can be used to force placement.  But, I'm curious and haven't found a solid answer.  So, does including the same figure placement specifier multiple times increase its weighting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It doesn't matter how many times you use the placement specifiers. And the sequence you use doesn't matter either. The specifiers only tell LaTeX which position is *allowed*.

For example, `htbp` works the same as `tpbhhhtpb`.

Comment: I'd like to think that "tpbhhhtpb" is the sound LaTeX makes at you as it still puts the float where you might not expect it to end up.

Comment: However, adding `!`, as in `tpbhhhtpb!!!!!`, does give LaTeX some encouragement, by asking it to ignore some rules on how many floats can be on one page, and the fraction of the page taken up by floats. Again, only the first `!` has an effect.